# Powershell to target users or groups that are not inherited from above folder

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way to write a powershell script that will return result for all folders that contain users or groups that are not inherited. I tried to run the script for non-inherited folders, but some of them are inherited...while have users/groups that were added later on without disabling the inheritance of the folder.

This is the script I found:

```
DIR "\\path\abc" -directory -recurse | GET-ACL | where {$_.Access.IsInherited -eq $false}|Select-Object PSPATH |Export-Csv "c:\export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Problem with this script is it reads the folder inheritance, and not the users/groups. What is the powershell cmdlet to target users/groups without inheritance?

Below is an example of the folder in question:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pscJQ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think you ACL logic is actually correct. I'm guessing by the `select-object PSPATH...` that you may be inadvertently modifying the data before you export it.

If I do this:

`(get-acl FolderName).Access`

I can clearly see that any item set directly on this ACL has a property of IsInherited that is set to false.

One of the challenges with Pipelines is that you often are in a scope that doesn't have the previous scope's data. The trick to that is to know when to break out into a foreach instead of continuing to go deeper down the pipe. Try this:

```
$NonInheritedPermissions = @()
dir -directory -recurse | % {
  $staticACLEntry = (get-acl $_).access | where {$_.IsInherited -eq $false}
  $NonInheritedPermissions += "Path:$($_.fullname);Identity:$(staticACLEntry.IdentityReference);FileSystemRights:$(staticACLEntry.FileSystemRights)"
}
$NonInheritedPermissions | export-csv some.csv
```

This is quick and dirty but you should be able to see how to break out the individual properties should you want to do a better job formatting. I would usually toss data like this into a PS object but I'm headed out the door.